# Where can I find a free Russian Bible other than the Russian Synodal Translation?

Tags: bible-translation, resource-request

I am considering to translate my book into Russian.

A stopper for this is that the standard Russian Bible (Russian Synodal Translation) is out of question **very** poor quality. (I once compared it with the Hebrew/Greek original, and it seems that more than half verses are with errors.)

Where can I get a good free complete translation of Bible into Russian language?

Comment: http://www.biblegateway.com/versions/Slovo-Zhizny-SZ-Bible/

Comment: https://www.youversion.com/ has eleven Russian versions, according to their Android app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a browsable Bible in Russian:
http://allbible.info/bible/modern/

Answer (score 0):

**New World Translation**: [English](http://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/), [Russian](http://www.jw.org/ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F/nwt/%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8/).

You can read the entire Bible online or download the PDF version of it. You can switch between languages using the drop-down bar on the right of the screen. There are about 600 languages we translate into.

If you would like a hard copy then you can request one here — [Contact for Russia](http://www.jw.org/en/jehovahs-witnesses/contact/russia/). We give them out at no charge to you.